# Run VBA when Check box changes

Tags: excel, vba

I have VBA to hide columns based on a list drop down and an activeX check box.  When the check box is selected or unselected the code for the columns visibilty doesn't rerun unless you change the dropdown selection a second time.  How would I get it to detect checkbox change and refresh?
The dropdown has this code but the checkbox has no code yet.
The dropdown is to select a type of formatted sheet so that when it is selcted only those columns will show.  When the checkbox is checked and a type is chosen from the dropdown then only those related columns will show.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Target.Address = "$D$11" Then
    If Target.Value = "A" Or Target.Value = "B" Then
        Sheets("Worksheet").Columns("BL:CH").Hidden = True
    ElseIf Target.Value = "C" And Not Me.CheckBox1.Value Then
        Sheets("Worksheet").Columns("BL:BY").Hidden = False
    ElseIf Target.Value = "C" And Me.CheckBox1.Value Then
        Sheets("Worksheet").Columns("BL:BY").Hidden = True
        Sheets("Worksheet").Columns("BZ:CH").Hidden = False
    End If
  End If
End Sub

This is the code I have on the CheckBox as a workaround for the moment.
The checkBox and Dropdown are in one sheet and the columns being
hidden are in another sheet.

Sub CheckBox1_Click()
   If CheckBox1.Value = True Then
      MsgBox "Reselect A"
   Else
      MsgBox "Reselect A, B or C"
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: usually one would start with Unhiding all columns, then gong through the various options and hiding what should be hidden.

Comment: Also you should have the hiding of the rows in its own sub and then call that sub when the correct cell changes and/or when the checkbox changes using that event.

Comment: Double-click the ActiveX checkbox control, it should create an event handler for its `Change` event.

Comment: FYI you can use `Me` in place of `Sheets("Worksheet")` if that's where the code is running.

Comment: Maybe try like this: make one more sub, say sub HideColumn, something like this `with range("D11"): if .value = "A" or .value = "B": then....: elseif .value = "C" and CheckBox1.value = false: then ... :elseif .value = "C" and checkbox1.value = true: then ...: end with`. Then in the worksheet_change sub : `If Target.Address = "$D$11" Then call HideColumn` ... and in the CheckBox1_Click sub, right after the `end if` also call that HideColumn sub.

Comment: Perfect!!  Thank you very much for the guidance.  This is what I needed for it to work properly without having to select the type twice.  I removed that from the code and it is awesome.